# Resource ID #7/#8

Tags: php

A message keeps saying resource id #7 (sometimes 8) when I query.

I know it's to do with fetch_array but this creates further problems because i fetch_array later on in my php?

```
                        $numeroOption= $_POST['numero'];
                        $selectOption = $_POST['parkname'];
                        $query = "SELECT * FROM `ROOMS` WHERE `Capacity` < '$numeroOption'"; 
                        $result = mysql_query($query);
                        echo $result;
                        if ($result == FALSE) die ("could not execute statement $query<br />");

                        echo "<table>"; 
                        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){   
                        echo "<tr><td>" . $row['roomCode'] . "</td></tr>";
                        }

                        echo "</table>"; 

                        mysql_close(); 
                        }
?>
```

Comment: `echo $result;` <- You need to fetch your results, as you do further down in the code.

Comment: So where should i add this? If i fetch them from the $result, it tells me it expects parmeter 1 to be a resource?@Rizier123

Comment: `$result` is a resource, so if you try to simply print it you get: `Resource ID #X`

Comment: @Rizier123 thank you!

Comment: Also see: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php